# Wants to call a function after time interval in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, scheduling

My problem is that I have a function implemented on my website which searches for Particular Tweets when I press the button. I want it to make it automatic such that, that function is called again and again after every two minutes, regardless some one uses the website or not..
I have a only a space piece of idea. Such as using a web service. Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a System.Timers.Timer in Global.asax.

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerElapsed), null, new Timespan(0), new Timespan(24, 0, 0));

// This will run every 24 hours.
private void TimerElapsed(object o)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Not working for. Saying something about directives and bunch of other errors

Comment: @HassamUllahSheikh Please provide more details, errors and ur code.

Comment: Well I didnt write any code myself I just copy pasted your code

Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'SmartyPlants.Global.TimerElapsed(object)' C:\Users\Hassam Sheikh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\mistersmartyplants - Copy\trunk\SmartyPlants\Global.asax.cs 44  SmartyPlants


Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Timespan' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Hassam Sheikh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\mistersmartyplants - Copy\trunk\SmartyPlants\Global.asax.cs SmartyPlants

Comment: You should add "using XXX" to import required namespaces at the head of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer, declared in global.asax, like this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 2000 * 60;
    timer.Elapsed += Myhandler;
    timer.Start();

    Application.Add("timer", timer);
}

static void Myhandler(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
}
```